# Connect 12V digital LED strip to Arduino

Tags: arduino, led, led-strip

How to connect a T12V-10L-30LED-W LED strip to an Arduino?

[Here](http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/c775b42bcf29a290d0ea4f876f35b6ea/HC-T12V-10L-30LED.pdf) is the strip specification.
And here the actual image of the strip: [image: strip]

The package says:
VCC: RED
GND: WHITE
DAT: GREEN

My question now is: Does the DAT input take 12V or something else? And how to wire this with an external 12V power source?

Comment: The datasheet apparently shows 12V connected to the "Data" pin instead of the "12V" pin. Conclusion : The datasheet is not trustworthy. If you cannot find better data, don't buy the product. (You may find better data on the named IC, WS2811S. Follow that, NOT this datasheet...

Comment: I don't think a duplicate.  The LED strip the OP refers to has a built in chip to receive data (WS2811S).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet isn't that helpful =(

But to power your led strip you need an external 12V supply, for that you can either:

Get a power converter (similar to phone charger) - Or battery - and power the arduino using it(through the arduino's DC 2.1mm jack).Then connect your LED strip to the Vin pin - not the 5V! - and ground the strip directly to the power supply since the arduino can't sink more than 0.2amps.

OR

get a power converter from a regular electronics store and just cut the wires and connect them directly to your strip.
Make sure you get one that can provide 12V and supply at least 0.6amp for every one meter of the strip.

OR

you can get a 12V battery instead and connect them to the strip directly.

As for the Data line,there's not much i can help you with but it seems like your going to need to do some testing.

Someone please correct me if i'm wrong...

Power the LED strip and connect the DATA line to an analog pin and then increase the AnalogWrite from 0(0V) all the way to 255(5V). What you're looking for here is to see if it works on 5V or 3.3V. Or if the DATA line actually takes an analog input.

Comment: Thanks Mero55! Found the WS2811S specifications [here](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf).
They are digital and running on 5V, so I used [this library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel). Connected the strip to a 12V 2A power converter. And the DAT input to the 5V digital output of the Arduino. If you cannot control your LEDs correctly (flashing LEDs/wrong color) wire an extra cable from GND of the strip to your Arduino, this keeps the signal clean. In addition to that, my LED strip was wrongly wired. Its not wired RGB but BRG.

Comment: Keep in mind that "number of LEDs" in this library means "number of controllers". On my LED strip 3 LEDs are connected to one controller.

Comment: Your wrong on the data line...

Comment: DAT takes 5V, drive it from the Arduino output. Connect Arduino GND to the led strip GND too. It is the easiest to use a library for that, check out Adafruit Neopixel uberguide. Please note that you may need to put a series resistor of 330-470 ohm between arduio and the DAT (technical reasons: ground bouncing on the strip can render DAT input of the driver chip out of range).